# Out of Memoy when tf.extract_image_patches is called

Tags: python, tensorflow

I built an input pipeline for a Convolutional Neural network using tensorflow.
In particular, at evaluation time, I need to read an image from the disk and generate several ( it could be 100000) patches from it. This is done using *tf.extract_image_patches*.
Then, I create batches (each of 2000 patches) and I feed them to the network.

The problem is that the program allocates the whole tensor of the patches, causing an Out Of Memory issue of my 4GB GPU.
I would expect that it just needs to allocate the batch involved in the evaluation at each step.
Is there a workaround to avoid this?

*Error*

```
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[104720,50,50,3]

     [[Node: Cast = Cast[DstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_UINT8, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](MirrorPad/_63)]]

     [[Node: Gather/_65 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_22_Gather", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

*Minimal Code*

```
imagepath = tf.convert_to_tensor(imagepath, dtype=tf.string)
image= tf.train.slice_input_producer(imagepath,shuffle=False,num_epochs=1)
image = tf.read_file(image)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
image=tf.extract_image_patches(image, ksizes=[1,50, 50,1], strides=[1,25,25,1], rates=[1,1,1,1],padding="VALID")
image=tf.reshape(image,(-1,50,50,3))

X = tf.train.batch([image], batch_size=2000,
                            capacity=batch_size * 8,
                                num_threads=1,
                                allow_smaller_final_batch=True,
                                enqueue_many=True
                                )
```

Comment: what is the dimension of each patch?

Comment: It is 50 x 50 x 3. The total number of patches is 104720

Comment: Is `batch_size` set to 104720?

Comment: Now, all the parameters are defined